# Variable length 'yield'?

Tags: python, generator, enumerate

I'd like to be able to `yield` a variable number of items which would allow a generator function something like the following to be written:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [4, 5, 6]
z = [7, 8, 9]

def multi_enumerate(*iterables):
    n = 0
    iterators = map(iter, iterables)
    while iterators:
        yield n, *tuple(map(next, iterators))  # invalid syntax
        n += 1

for i,a,b,c in multi_enumerate(x, y, z):
    print i,a,b,c
```

Anyone know of some way to do this? I know I can yield a tuple, but that would require explicitly unpacking it on the receiving end such as: `a,b,c = t[0], t[1], t[2]`.

**Final Solution**:

FWIW, here's what I ended up using, based on John Kugelman's excellent answer:

```
from itertools import izip

def multi_enumerate(*iterables, **kwds):
    start = kwds.get('start')
    if start is None:
        if kwds: raise TypeError(
            "multi_enumerate() accepts only the keyword argument 'start'")
        try:
            iter(iterables[-1])  # last non-keyword arg something iterable?
        except TypeError:        # no, assume it's the start value
            start, iterables = iterables[-1], iterables[:-1]
        else:
            start = 0  # default

    return ((n,)+t for n, t in enumerate(izip(*iterables), start))
```

The added code is because of my desire to make it also accept an optional non-iterable last argument to specify a starting value other than 0 (or specify it using a `start` keyword argument), just like the built-in `enumerate()` function.

Comment: Are you looking for `zip` or `izip`?

Comment: `yield` is, in a sense, like `return` - you can yield the same amount of things that you can return.  That is to say, one *thing*, but you could return the tuple of all of your arguments.

Comment: If you want to just combine the iterables into one generator, use `itertools.izip`

Comment: @Makoto: Yes, good point. The crux of the problem was I wasn't realizing that if the function simply `yield`ed a _single_ tuple, then that could be split up properly on the receiving end. The answer I accepted addressed that and then some.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the `yield` statement to this:

```
yield (n,) + tuple(map(next, iterators))
```

Or use `izip` and `enumerate` to eliminate the whole loop:

```
from itertools import izip

def multi_enumerate(*iterables):
    return ((n,) + t for n, t in enumerate(izip(*iterables)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`chain`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) from [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html):

```
yield tuple(chain((n,), map(next, iterators)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return an iterator that produces `(n, *l[n])` for `i` `n`-length `l`s.  It will work directly in place of your `multienumerate` method.

```
from itertools import izip
def enumerated_columns(*rows):
    return izip(range(len(rows[0])), *rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *delegate* several items from your generator to some other generator, there's no one-line way to do this — unless you use Python 3.3 that [features `yield from`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/).

I'd iterate over the nested generators yielding values from them explicitly, something like

```
yield n
for value in (delegated.next for delegated in iterators):
  yield value
```